# How to state abbreviations inside brackets?

Tags: grammar, abbreviations, convention

I am aware of the convention of stating an abbreviation in brackets the first time it is used, e.g. "I did well in the Biology Admissions Test (BAT)".

However, I am having difficulties with when you are already writing inside a bracket, e.g. "(I did well in the Biology Admissions Test (BAT))". I am not sure if using a bracket inside a bracket is correct. Would something like "(I did well in the Biology Admissions Test, or BAT)" be more appropriate?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with nested parenthesis, within reason. Your use case is very well within reason.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. Is there some sort of dis-allowance pulled over you? Nobody put strict rules on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your style guide. [APA](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/abbreviations/) uses brackets:

> When the spelled-out version first appears in parentheses, put the abbreviation in brackets after it:
>
> **Example:** The diagnosis (i.e., attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder [ADHD]) was confirmed via behavioral observation.